# Accessing redux store using redux-hooks (useSelector)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

In my component I am using useSelector hook to grab an array of objects from my store. Then I am parsing the results in a function. However, the issue is that when the component renders the function returns "-Infinity" and then it re-renders again to the correct value.

Below is console log of prices array map based on the hotelList.

[image: Result of console.log(prices) inside getMaxPrice function]

Here is my code:

```
const hotelList = useSelector(state => state.hotels)

  const getMaxPrice = () => {
    const prices = hotelList.map(
      ({ fields: { pricePerNight } }) => pricePerNight
    )
    console.log(prices)

    const max = Math.max(...prices)

    return max.toString()
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    price: getMaxPrice(),
    stars: ""
  })
```

I think useSelector access store asynchronously therefore it is not available at first place. Is there a way to ensure that my hotelList is fully fetched from the store before continuing?

Comment: maybe, hotelList is null on the first render.

Answer (score 1):

The very first time the array is empty and `Math.max(...[])` returns `-Infinity`. In some cases using `...` spread operator will fail as suggested on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) . The safe way to do what you want is

```
var max = prices.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
});
```